# Filtro com javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho o script abaixo que tem como objetivo buscar pelo texto dos blocos, porém a busca é realizada apenas até o primeiro paragrafo, depois não encontra a palavra, exemplo: pesquisar por costa e silva, não encontra essa palavra, mas ela existe.

```js
<script>
$(function(){ 

  $("#filtro").keyup(function(){
    var texto = $(this).val();
    
    $(".bloco").each(function(){
      var resultado = $(this).text().toUpperCase().indexOf(' '+texto.toUpperCase());
      
      if(resultado < 0) {
        $(this).fadeOut();
      }else {
        $(this).fadeIn();
      }
    }); 

  });

});
</script>
```

```html
<DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="estilo.css"/>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script> 
 <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>  
<head>
</head>
<body>

<div class="busca">
   <input id="filtro" type="text" placeholder="Busca Rápida">
</div>
<div class="blocos">
  <div class="bloco">
    <h3>meu nome</h3>
    <p>minha descricao</p>
 <p>meu bairro</p>
  </div>
  
  <div class="bloco">
    <h3>outro nome</h3>
    <p>outra descricao</p>
 <p>costa e silva</p>
  </div>
  
  <div class="bloco">
    <h3>nome</h3>
    <p>descricao</p>
 <p>joão costa</p>
  </div>
  
  <div class="bloco">
    <h3>nome</h3>
    <p>descricao</p>
 <p>costa e silva</p>
  </div>
  
  <div class="bloco">
    <h3>nome</h3>
    <p>descricao</p>
 <p>bairro</p>
  </div>
  
  <div class="bloco">
    <h3>nome</h3>
    <p>descricao</p>
 <p>bairro</p>
  </div>  

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Creio que você podia dar uma olhada sobre REGEX em Javascript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você está utilizando `indexOf(' '+texto.toUpperCase())`, mas por que o espaço antes do texto?

Note que o seu HTML está indentado com espaços na primeira e segunda linha, porém a terceira linha está indentada com um tab, e por isso você não consegue encontrar o texto, porque ele não está precedido de um espaço comum, mas sim de um tab.

Sua opção é alterar a indentação, ou o método que você faz a pesquisa.